# Loss of context draggable jquery-ui on Angular in setInterval

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, setinterval

I don't know how to explain it properly, but I will try.

My application use: angular (7), jquery-ui, fullcalendar (v3)

```
this.intervalExTrips = setInterval(this.updateExTrips.bind(this), 10000);
```

updateExTrips() - async request to server (function) for getting external events for the calendar. Request use `return new Promise`

Before the request i initialize the component by adding it

```
    $(el).draggable({
                  zIndex: 2,
                  scroll: false,
                  appendTo: 'body',
                  ....
    })
```

after execution updateExTrips, it flies off draggable.
In other words, it is possible to move an element before calling the function, but not after executing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help me ChangeDetectorRef

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Necessary call after updating the data

```
this.http.get<Trip[]>('/trip/')
     .subscribe(
     ...
     this.cd.detectChanges(); 
     ...
     //redraw and add $(el).draggable({
     );
```